# Can Samsung Windows Phones use the Swype keyboard interface?

Tags: apps, settings, autocorrect

Samsung is known for pioneering [Swype](http://www.swype.com/) in its own and Android smartphones. Its an efficient way to do keyboard input. On my Samsung Focus S, is there anyway to enable a Swype keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

At this time there is no official* way to enable Swype on any Windows Device. There is a [UserVoice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions) set up. Add the suggestion there, and just maybe it will come in future version.

<sup>* It is possible some homebrew way exists, but I imagine you need to have your device rooted and unlocked for it to work. I just don't know of any</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No, currently it is not possible to change the SIP (Software Input Panel, or on screen keyboard) in any way on Windows Phone 7. This means: no Swype, unless Microsoft adds it (or a way to customize SIPs) to any next version.